# Matlab - how to remove a line break when printing to screen?

Tags: matlab

There is for example a big big score

for 2 hours

and there is need to see how many more before the end of

do output on the screen of the outer loop

but the values ​​and there are many, such as 70 000

Question - how to remove a line break when printing to screen

not to receive 70 000 lines

and to see only the current display in one line?

Comment: What does you data look like? Are you reading from a file? And could you share the code you are currently using to print the data? That will give us a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function, which you can use in place of `disp` for a string argument. It displays to the command window, and remembers the message it has displayed. When you call it the next time, it first deletes the previous output from the command window (using ASCII backspace characters), then prints the new message.

In this way you only get to see the last message, and the command window doesn't fill up with old messages.

```
function teleprompt(s)
%TELEPROMPT prints to the command window, over-writing the last message
%
%       TELEPROMPT(S)
%       TELEPROMPT()      % Terminate
%
%       Input S is a string.

persistent lastMsg

if isempty(lastMsg)
    lastMsg = '';
end

if nargin == 0
    lastMsg = [];
    fprintf('\n');
    return
end

fprintf(repmat('\b', 1, numel(sprintf(lastMsg))));
fprintf(s);

lastMsg = s;
```

Comment: Can you give an example of use?

for i = 1:10
teleprompt (i);
end

so?

Comment: You have to pass it a string, whereas your `i` is a double. So: `for i = 1:10, teleprompt(sprintf('%s', i)), end`

Comment: Thank you very much helped me!     When the issue
Warning: Escape sequence '\' is not valid. See 'help sprintf' for valid escape sequences.
> In teleprompt at 19

Comment: I think you must be trying to print a string with a `'\'` in it? Best avoided, but if you really need to do this, use a double `'\\'`.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using `disp` to display text to the screen, use `fprintf`, which requires you to enter line breaks manually.

Compare

```
>> disp('Hello, '), disp('World')
Hello, 
World
```

with

```
>> fprintf('Hello, '), fprintf('World\n')
Hello, World
```

The `\n` at the end of `'World\n'` signifies a line break (or *newline* as they're commonly called).

Comment: for i=1:10
fprintf('%6.2f \n', i)
end   
  1.00 
  2.00 
  3.00 
  4.00 
  5.00 
  6.00 
  7.00 
  8.00 
  9.00 
 10.00   We get 10 rows.
But I do not need a rows

Comment: So remove the \n from your string!